# keep only rows in file that occur n times

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a `test.txt` file that contains one string per row as follows:

```
AA
BNT
AA
KIO
LO
LO
POY
LO
II
LO
AA
AA
II
AA
BNT
POY
YTR
BNT
LL
BNT
```

How can I use linux to go through the file and return only rows that occur 4 times?

Desired output:

```
AA
BNT
LO
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean rows that occur four times or more? `AA` only appears five times but you have it in your output.

Comment: Is the order of the output significant?

Comment: no the order is not important. thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AWK:

```
awk '{ seen[$0]++ } seen[$0] == 4' test.txt
```

This counts the number of times each line has been seen, and outputs a line when the count is exactly four (so lines seen four or more times are output once).

If you only want to see lines which appear exactly four times, use this instead:

```
awk '{ seen[$0]++ } END { for (line in seen) if (seen[line] == 4) print line }' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort test.txt | uniq -c | awk '$1==4 {print $2}'
```

With `sort` and `uniq` used for counting occurences, while `awk` selects when 4 occurences are found.

For 4 and more occurences, just change `$1==4` to `$1>=4`.

Note that this works for single-string lines only and output is sorted lexographically.